# Multiple publisher in ZeroMQ C++ Is this a good choice or not?

Tags: c++, zeromq

I am new to ZeroMQ. I want to create multiple publishers, where each publisher is publishing specific data, such as following:

1. Publisher 1: Publishing image data
2. Publisher 2: Publishing audio data
3. Publisher 3: Publishing text data

Basically, my requirement is to publish the data from multiple publishers and receive using multiple receivers on the other side.

Please see the sample code below:

**data_publisher.cpp**

```
//  Prepare our context and all publishers
zmq::context_t context(1);
zmq::socket_t publisher1(context, ZMQ_PUB);
zmq::socket_t publisher2(context, ZMQ_PUB);
zmq::socket_t publisher3(context, ZMQ_PUB);
zmq::socket_t publisher4(context, ZMQ_PUB);

publisher1.bind("tcp://*:5556");
publisher2.bind("tcp://*:5557");
publisher3.bind("tcp://*:5558");
publisher4.bind("tcp://*:5559");

//  Initialize random number generator
srandom((unsigned)time(NULL));
while (1) {
    // sample data
    int zipcode1 = within(100000);
    int zipcode2 = within(100000);
    int zipcode3 = within(100000);
    int zipcode4 = within(100000);

    int temperature1 = within(215) - 80;
    int temperature2 = within(215) - 80;
    int temperature3 = within(215) - 80;
    int temperature4 = within(215) - 80;

    int relhumidity1 = within(50) + 10;
    int relhumidity2 = within(50) + 10;
    int relhumidity3 = within(50) + 10;
    int relhumidity4 = within(50) + 10;

    zmq::message_t message1(20);
    zmq::message_t message2(20);
    zmq::message_t message3(20);
    zmq::message_t message4(20);

    snprintf((char*)message1.data(), 20, "%05d %d %d", zipcode1, temperature1, relhumidity1);
    snprintf((char*)message2.data(), 20, "%05d %d %d", zipcode2, temperature2, relhumidity2);
    snprintf((char*)message3.data(), 20, "%05d %d %d", zipcode3, temperature3, relhumidity3);
    snprintf((char*)message4.data(), 20, "%05d %d %d", zipcode4, temperature4, relhumidity4);

    publisher1.send(message1);
    publisher2.send(message2);
    publisher3.send(message3);
    publisher4.send(message4);
}
```

**data_receiver.cpp**

```
zmq::context_t context(1);

//  Socket to talk to server
zmq::socket_t subscriber1(context, ZMQ_SUB);
zmq::socket_t subscriber2(context, ZMQ_SUB);
zmq::socket_t subscriber3(context, ZMQ_SUB);
zmq::socket_t subscriber4(context, ZMQ_SUB);

subscriber1.connect("tcp://localhost:5556");
subscriber2.connect("tcp://localhost:5557");
subscriber3.connect("tcp://localhost:5558");
subscriber4.connect("tcp://localhost:5559");

const char* filter = (argc > 1) ? argv[1] : "10001 ";
subscriber1.setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, filter, strlen(filter));
subscriber2.setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, filter, strlen(filter));
subscriber3.setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, filter, strlen(filter));
subscriber4.setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, filter, strlen(filter));

//  Process 100 updates
int update_nbr;
long total_temp1 = 0;
long total_temp2 = 0;
long total_temp3 = 0;
long total_temp4 = 0;

for (update_nbr = 0; update_nbr < 100; update_nbr++)
{
    zmq::message_t update1;
    zmq::message_t update2;
    zmq::message_t update3;
    zmq::message_t update4;
    int zipcode1, temperature1, relhumidity1;
    int zipcode2, temperature2, relhumidity2;
    int zipcode3, temperature3, relhumidity3;
    int zipcode4, temperature4, relhumidity4;

    subscriber1.recv(&update1);
    subscriber2.recv(&update2);
    subscriber3.recv(&update3);
    subscriber4.recv(&update4);

    std::istringstream iss1(static_cast<char*>(update1.data()));
    std::istringstream iss2(static_cast<char*>(update2.data()));
    std::istringstream iss3(static_cast<char*>(update3.data()));
    std::istringstream iss4(static_cast<char*>(update4.data()));

    iss1 >> zipcode1 >> temperature1 >> relhumidity1;
    iss2 >> zipcode2 >> temperature2 >> relhumidity2;
    iss3 >> zipcode3 >> temperature3 >> relhumidity3;
    iss4 >> zipcode4 >> temperature4 >> relhumidity4;

    total_temp1 += temperature1;
    total_temp2 += temperature2;
    total_temp3 += temperature3;
    total_temp4 += temperature4;
}

std::cout << "Average temperature for zipcode '" << filter << "' was "
          << (int)(total_temp1 / update_nbr) << "F" << std::endl;
std::cout << "Average temperature for zipcode '" << filter << "' was "
          << (int)(total_temp2 / update_nbr) << "F" << std::endl;
std::cout << "Average temperature for zipcode '" << filter << "' was "
          << (int)(total_temp3 / update_nbr) << "F" << std::endl;
std::cout << "Average temperature for zipcode '" << filter << "' was "
          << (int)(total_temp4 / update_nbr) << "F" << std::endl;
```

Please note that the above code is a sample code to get the suggestions / advice.

**I want to know if it is a good choice or not as shown in the sample code above?**

Comment: Ok, you ask Community Members to suggest / advise, but you have **not expressed any single measure** to use to decide what is good choice with respect to some assessment metric ( the best a quantitative one ). **So, kindly share** with us, mortals, **how do you decide on your own what is a set of features and qualities a good design in your opinion has and what is a sign of a not good design, ok?**

Comment: @user3666197: I want to create multiple *publishers* but I am not sure if creating multiple instances of `zmq::socket_t` is a good idea or not. Thanks for your kind cooperation.

Comment: How do you measure goodness? Do you want to know if it's maintainable? Or if meets some latency requirement? Or a bandwidth requirement? Or something else?

Comment: @Useless: my current concern is speed. Since the data is huge, that is why I am planning to have multiple *publishers* on separate port. I would like to receive the data as fast as possible from *publisher*.

Comment: ***Speed***? Be rather quantitative, ok? Express this as a maximum duration in [ms], [us] or [ns] for some activity to happen, **right?** Next, ***huge***? Be rather quantitative, ok? Express this as a maximum size in [kB], [MB] or [GB] for an object of interest + how often it has to re-process such an item in time in [1/s] or [kHz] et al, **right?** Next, **what are your resources -- RAM, CPU, cache, LAN / other non-local transport interconnects ...** where do you plan to operate the processing, **right?**

Comment: + as was asked and misleadingly answered in your other question -- most distributed-systems programming **never allows a blocking** mode of any `.recv()` to ever happen, it is an awfully bad habit even for a school-book grade examples, as it is a resources devastating anti-pattern for any professionally meant software ( MANY TIMES MORE IN ROBOTICS AND ANY SIMILAR REAL-TIME-CONTROL SYSTEM ). Always expect not to wait a nanosecond on any attempt to receive using **`.recv( ..., ZMQ_DONTWAIT )`** and rather pre-`poll()` or just loop-through with a due ex-post return code handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Still waiting for any quantitative fact, but let's start:

ZeroMQ is a concept of using smart enabling tools, whereas the low-level system programming is hidden by the ZeroMQ core element, the **`Context`**-engine.

This said, the high-level tools, formalised as Scalable Formal Communication Pattern Archetypes, deliver some sort of human-mimicking behaviour -- `PUB` Publishers indeed "publish", **`SUB`** Subscribers can "subscribe", **`REQ`** Requestors can "request", **`REP`** Repliers can indeed "reply", etc.

These AccessPoints with behaviour can **`.bind()/.connect()`** into some sort of a distributed-behavioural infrastructure, once having been granted some elementary rules. One of such rule is do not bother with actual transport-classes', all being indeed feature-rich technologies, currently spanning landscapes of `{ inproc:// | ipc:// | tcp:// | pgm:// | epgm:// | vmci:// }`,  low-level details, the **`Context()`**-instance will handle all these 
transparently to your high-level behaviour. Simply forget about this. Another rule is, you can be sure every message sent is either delivered error-free or not at all - no compromise in this, no tortured trash ever delivered to fool or crash the recipient's AccessPoint post-processing.

Failing to understand this, ZeroMQ is not used to it's maximum to deliver us both the comfort and the powers that were engineered into this luxurious tool.

### Back to your dilemma:

Having said the few remarks above and having your primary architecture not clear yet, it is still possible to help you here.

ZeroMQ abstract, distributed-behaviour Socket-tool is principally a pure-**`[SERIAL]`** schedulling device. This means, none of any of your receiving AccessPoints `{ .bind() | .connect() }`-associated with a Socket can expect to arbitrarily re-order a pure-sequantial flow of messages.

This means, in any case, where either a "just"-**`[CONCURRENT]`** process-scheduling or in an extreme case, where a true-**`[PARALLEL]`** process-scheduling is technically orchestrated, a single "pure"-**`[SERIAL]`** delivery channel will not allow a `{ [CONCURRENT] | [PARALLEL] }`-system to keep delivering such mode of process-scheduling and will chop the flow of events / processing into a "pure"-**`[SERIAL]`** sequence of messages.

**A )** This indeed **could be both a reason and a must** for introducing multiple independently operated ZeroMQ distributed-behaviour Socket instances.

**B )** On the other side, not knowing anything about the global distributed-system behaviour, **no one can yet tell for sure**, whether going into multiple independently operated Socket instance is not just a waste of time and resources, delivering unreasonably under-average or unacceptably poor end-to-end system behaviour performance because of an extremely wrong or totally missing initial engineering decision.

---

## Performance?

Do not guess in this domain, never. Rather start with first quantitatively declared needs, based on which a technically reasoned design will be able to proceed and define all the steps needed in the resources mapping and performance tweaking up to the platform limits.

ZeroMQ has been for the last two decades gloriously equipped for doing this with ultimate performance characteristics and the Design & Engineering team has done a great deal in polishing both the scalability and performance envelopes, while keeping latency on level hardly to achieve by an ad-hoc programmer. Indeed a great piece of system-programming hidden in the ZeroMQ basement.

"*data is huge*" -- ok, **define the *size*** -- delivering **`1E+9`** messages having **`1 [B]`** in size has other performance tweaking than delivering 1E+3 messages having **`1.000.000 [B]`** in size.

"*as fast as possible*" -- ok, **define the *fast*** for a **given size** and intended cadence of messages 1/s ~ **`1 [Hz]`**, 10/s ~ **`10 [Hz]`**, 1000/s ~ **`1 [kHz]`**

Sure, under some certain circumstances such mix of requirements may wander outside of the contemporary computing-devices capabilities horizons. That has to get reviewed best before any programming has ever started, because otherwise you have just spoilt some amount of programming efforts on a thing, that will never fly, so better to have a positive proof of the solution architecture being feasible and doable within an acceptable resources and costs perimeter.

So, if your Project needs something, **first** define and quantitatively specify what that actually is, **next** the solution architecture can start to sort it out and provide decisions, what tools and what tool-configurations can match the defined target levels of functionality and performance objectives.

Building a house, having started by raising a roof will never answer the questions how to layout the basement wall a what would be a sufficient and yet not over-designed thickness of the iron-concrete armouring, that will carry an unknown amount of high-raised building floors. Having a roof already built is easy to show up, but has nothing to do with a systematic and rigorous design & engineering practice.